# How can i deny access to example.com/phpmyadmin on openlitespeed server?

Tags: .htaccess, phpmyadmin, .htpasswd, litespeed

i'd like to deny access to example.com/phpmyadmin or secure it with a password-prompt using .htaccess and .htpasswd.
Is that possible? If so,how can i achieve that?
I don't need to access phpmyadmin over the web.

I'm running an openlitespeed wordpress droplet on DigitalOcean.

Thanks for any help!

Cheers,

Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this [guide](https://docs.litespeedtech.com/cloud/wordpress/#how-do-i-secure-phpmyadmin)

If you don't need to visit it from browser at all:

> Just remove **phpmyadmin** from the **WebAdmin > Virtual Hosts >
>   Context**.

If you want to set password to protect it, follow Method 2 from the guide:

> 1. Log into SSH console and create a password file:
>      touch /usr/local/lsws/conf/PASS
>      chown lsadm:lsadm /usr/local/lsws/conf/PASS
> 2. Navigate to WebAdmin > Security
> 3. Set Realm Name = example, and User DB Location = /usr/local/lsws/conf/PASS
> 4. Click /usr/local/lsws/conf/PASS to create a user/password
> 5. Navigate to WebAdmin > Virtual Hosts > Context > phpmyadmin
> 6. Set Realm to example

Best

Comment: Thank you Eric! Worked great!

Comment: No problem, glade it helps ^ ^